# How to style non MUI Components with an MUI theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

For example if I dynamically needed to apply MUI theme to my non-MUI components, like an `<h1>`. If I want `<h1>` tags to always be the same color (from the theme color) and always use the same margin, how can I globally define that in the theme and not just generating it per-component. `<h1>` is just an example, but my concern extends to any third party component I may use in my app.

Comment: have the same question, did you solve this?

Comment: @EnricoPolanski never did

Comment: I think I found a solution, if you want I can post it later as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Asumming you have a ParentComponent and you wish to apply the styles to its children components:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  '@global': {
    '.children-css-selector': {
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }
  }
});

export default function ParentComponent() {
  useStyles();

  return (
       your code....
  )
}
```